# Does Python allow calls to decorator factory factories?

Tags: python, grammar

On  [Ian McCracken's blog](http://concisionandconcinnity.blogspot.com/), he has an [article where he talks about decorator factory factories](http://concisionandconcinnity.blogspot.com/2010/09/decorator-factories-and-decorator.html). In the article, he gives an example of one:

```
def decorator_factory_factory(method):
    def decorator_factory(regex):
        def decorator(f):
            def inner(*args, **kwargs):
                # do stuff with f(*args, **kwargs)
                # and method and regex
            return inner
        return decorator
    return decorator_factory
```

He then gives an example of how he could call the decorator:

```
@decorator_factory_factory('GET')('^/.*$')
def onGetAnything(self):
    pass
```

This caught my attention. I had never tried calling a decorator decorator factory before, so I decided to see how the code would behave:

```
>>> def decorator_factory_factory(method):
    def decorator_factory(regex):
        def decorator(f):
            def inner(*args, **kwargs):
                print(args, kwargs)
            return inner
        return decorator
    return decorator_factory

>>> @decorator_factory_factory('GET')('^/.*$')
def onGetAnything(self):
    pass
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

As you can see from above, Python raises a `SyntaxError`. Why is that? Besides the code apparently working for Mr. McCraken, it seems like code such should run perfectly fine. Isn't it basically the same syntax as chaining function calls together, which does work? eg:

```
>>> def foo():
    def bar():
        return 2
    return bar

>>> foo()()
2
>>>
```

I thought perhaps he was using an older version of Python which allowed such syntax, so I looked over the grammar for the Python version which he was probably using when he wrote the article back in 2009; 2.6.9. But [the grammar](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6c003210943fc91e5911bcbabe1fe4b0030cf38b/Grammar/Grammar) still doesn't seem to allow chained decorator calls:

> ```
> decorator: '@' dotted_name [ '(' [arglist] ')' ] NEWLINE
> decorators: decorator+
> decorated: decorators (classdef | funcdef)
> ```

Has this syntax ever been allowed in *any* Python version. If not, then how was Ian able to run his code? Did he simply make a mistake?

Comment: Almost certainly it's just the shell indenting the function definition. Do this in a file instead.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Nope. [It's still raising an error](https://repl.it/JJxJ/0).

Comment: I do not think that example provided in the article is valid. A decorator factory can be used to generate a decorator `GET = decorator_factory_factory('GET')` -> `@GET('regex')`, but I do not think it is possible to use decorators in the way author describes. Probably it is misleading. I would be happy to be wrong and get the detailed explanation, but it does not look like `out of the box` python behavior.

Comment: @Taras _" I would be happy to be wrong and get the detailed explanation"_ - You and me both. Although I'm starting to think your right, and that Ian simply made a mistake.

Comment: Naah, I've checked cpython tokenizer, it does not look like it will be able to parse a decorator out of a decorator. (Double '@' usage or smth like that). 
I think either author tried to explain why python decorators were not implemented in that way or have not understood decorators. 

It also does not look like author uses the magic.
https://github.com/iancmcc/txrestapi/blob/master/txrestapi/methods.py#L25

Comment: I have doubts if the original blogger has actually tried it. He wrote (shortened): _"I could have used the function ..... it's totally unreadable, so draw the line  ....."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, to get this working, you could make a `decorator_caller` decorator, that will make the calls for you:

```
def decorator_caller(decorator, args_list):
    d = decorator
    for args in args_list:
        d = d(*args)
    return d
```

Used like this:

```
@decorator_caller(decorator_factory_factory, (('GET',), ('^/.*$',)))
def onGetAnything(self):
    pass
```

Or using lists instead (since single item tuples look confusing):

```
@decorator_caller(decorator_factory_factory, (['GET'], ['^/.*$']))
def onGetAnything(self):
    pass
```

---

Note that I do not believe that such a factory factory is a useful thing to build. Factory factories make some sense when the outer factories will really affect the logic of the constructed inner factory. When all you’re doing is creating a temporary factory to create a single item just to throw away the factory immediately, then you don’t really gain anything except from more complexity and a worse overall performance.

This would be a different thing if you actually stored the factory around for reuse:

```
getFactory = decorator_factory_factory('GET')

@getFactory('^/index.*$')
def index():
    pass

@getFactory('^/.*$')
def x():
    pass
```

This makes sense and the syntax also works fine. But if you just want to chain factory calls to add another argument to configure the decorator, then you should just adjust the factory to take both those arguments.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Your right, you would have to store the factory factory. [Which is what the author did in their REST API](https://github.com/iancmcc/txrestapi/blob/master/txrestapi/methods.py). I was really just wondering whether is was possible or not. But I guess the answer looks to be a sound _"no"_, since all of the Python version grammars I've looked at would reject such syntax. Even versions as early as 2.4.